# Compiling moc files Qt 4.5.2 intrin.h unexpected type "void" Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2015

I have a project I have been compiling using visual studio 2008 for compatibility reasons. It has been a real pain and am testing compatibility with visual studio 2015. I have custom build steps for several qt object files to run through the MOC and then compile them along with the build. Whenever I try to compile one of the moc files in 2015, I get the following error sequence:

```
   moc_class.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\intrin.h(200): error C2062: type 'void' unexpected
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\intrin.h(200): error C2144: syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by '('
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\intrin.h(200): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\intrin.h(200): error C2365: '_InterlockedCompareExchange': redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
```

Any reason why this would occur? I am at a wall and can't seem to find any information on the issue. Using qt 4.5.2.

Comment: Qt *4.5.2*? That has been unsupported for *years* now and cannot possibly work with VS 2015.

Comment: @peppe New to the framework, didn't realize it was so ancient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt4 will not work under Visual Studio 2015 unless you build that version (4.5.2) of Qt from source yourself using the Visual Studio 2015.

Another option would be to change your project so that it becomes compatible with Qt5. You can read more about how to do it here: https://wiki.qt.io/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5 .

Comment: Ahh thanks! I was trying to find compatibility online but couldn't seem to find any qt doc on what it supports. Very helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. Keep in mind: the best way to thank on stackoverflow is to accept/upvote the answer that helped you, see why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/320234